# Calculate confidence interval of random + fixed effect coefficients in a mixed effect model in R

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, confidence-interval, statistics-bootstrap

I use the the lme4 package in R to fit a mixed effect model:

```
library(lme4)

model <- lmer(y~x1*x2+(1|subect)+(0 + x1+x2+x1:x2|subject)
```

If I would like to have total effect per subject that accounts for both fixed and random slopes, I can use the function coef which reports coefficients per subject.

```
coef(model)
```

Now, I would like to calculate confidence intervals on those estimates per subject accounting for both fixed and random effects CI. Do you have tips on how to do that in R?

Thank you!

Comment: maybe useful; https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#predictions-andor-confidence-or-prediction-intervals-on-predictions

Comment: There are three challenges here. The first is extracting and lining up the components of the fixed and random effects - the easiest thing to do there is probably to copy and extend the code of `lme4:::coef.merMod`.  The second and third (both shared by the task of finding confidence intervals on predictions) are (2) what to do about uncertainty in the top-level random effects parameters (i.e. the variances and covariances) (using parametric bootstrapping (slow) *or* ignoring this uncertainty) and (3) what to do about correlations between the fixed and random effects (ditto) ...

Comment: Thanks for thinking along ! If I understand your point correctly, then the following code applying bootstrapping should work to calculate CI on the subject level coefficient incorporating both fixed and random effects ?

`get_subject_coefficients <- function(data, indices) {
  sample_data <- data[indices,]
  sample_model <- lmer(
Y ~ x1 * x2 +(1|subect)+ (0 + x1 + x2 + x1:x2 |subject),data = sample_data)
  coefficients <- coef(sample_model)$subject %>% as.matrix()
  return(coefficients)}
boot_results <- boot(data = train_data, statistic = get_subject_coefficients, R = 1000)` @BenBolker

Comment: You have to be careful about bootstrapping because it doesn't respect the grouping variable.

Comment: Okay, but I believe the bootMer function would ? so replacing boot with bootMer should do the job ? or otherwise, incorporate a cluster bootstrap approach to respect the grouping variable in the linear mixed-effects model? @BenBolker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I show three ways to get these values:

- adding the variances of the fixed and random effects components and computing Normal CIs, using a modified/hacked version of the `lme4:::coef.merMod()` function. This assumes (1) that the sampling distributions of these components are Normal, and (2) that the variance in the fixed and random effects are independent. (Also not making any finite-size corrections)
- Parametric bootstrap with `bootMer()`. This assumes that the model is correct
- Nonparametric bootstrapping with `lmeresampler`. This makes weaker assumptions, but would be difficult to implement a case with (e.g.) crossed random effects (this package offers a few alternative methods, e.g. residual or Wild bootstrapping ...)

There's a reasonable discussion of nonparametric vs parametric bootstraps
[here](https://influentialpoints.com/Training/nonparametric-or-parametric_bootstrap.htm)

All three methods give *reasonably* similar results in this (pretty well-behaved) example ...

The code below is a little ugly, could probably be cleaned up (I mostly avoided tidyverse, which might actually be useful ...)

### load packages and fit basic model

```r
library(lme4)
library(ggplot2)
library(lmeresampler)
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
```

### parametric bootstrap

```r
f <- function(x) unlist(coef(x)$Subject)
b <- bootMer(fm1, FUN = f, seed = 101, nsim = 1000,
             use.u = TRUE,  ## important - *don't* resample RE values
             parallel = "multicore", ncpus = 5)
## rearrange
bootmer_res <- t(apply(as.data.frame(b), 2, quantile, c(0.025, 0.975)))
bootmer_res <- setNames(as.data.frame(bootmer_res), c("lwr", "upr"))
```

### sum of variances

```r
cc <- coef2.merMod(fm1)  ## defined below
coef_res <- data.frame(unlist(cc$values$Subject + qnorm(0.025)*cc$sd$Subject),
                       unlist(cc$values$Subject + qnorm(0.975)*cc$sd$Subject))
coef_res <- setNames(as.data.frame(coef_res), c("lwr", "upr"))
```

### nonparametric bootstrap

```r
set.seed(101)
dd <- bootstrap(fm1, .f = f, type = "case", B = 1000, 
     ## resample only within Subjects
     resample = c(FALSE, TRUE))
lmeresamp_res <- t(apply(dd$replicates, 2, quantile, c(0.025, 0.975)))
lmeresamp_res <- setNames(as.data.frame(lmeresamp_res), c("lwr", "upr"))
```

### combine estimates and plot

```r
all_res <- rbind(transform(bootmer_res, nm = "bootmer"),
                 transform(coef_res, nm = "coef2"),
                 transform(lmeresamp_res, nm = "lmeresamp"))
## better to do this by manipulating existing metadata (e.g. rownames)
nsubj <- 18
all_res$var <- rep(rep(c("(Intercept)", "Days"), each = nsubj), 3)
all_res$subj <- rep(seq(nsubj), 6)
ggplot(all_res, aes(xmin = lwr, xmax = upr, y = subj, colour = nm)) +
    facet_wrap(~var, scale = "free") +
    geom_linerange(position = position_dodge(width = 0.5))
                  
ggsave("coef_SDs.png")
```

[image]

---

### coef2.merMod() function

```r
coef2.merMod <- function (object, ...)  {
    fef <- data.frame(rbind(fixef(object)), check.names = FALSE)
    fef_var <- data.frame(rbind(diag(vcov(object))), check.names = FALSE) ## *
    ref <- ranef(object, condVar = TRUE)  ## *
    refnames <- unlist(lapply(ref, colnames))
    nmiss <- length(missnames <- setdiff(refnames, names(fef)))
    if (nmiss > 0) {
        fillvars <- setNames(data.frame(rbind(rep(0, nmiss))), 
            missnames)
        fef <- cbind(fillvars, fef)
        fef_var <- cbind(fillvars, ref_var)
    }
    dfun <- function(x) lapply(ref, function(y) x[rep.int(1L, nrow(y)), , drop = FALSE])
    val <- dfun(fef)
    val_var <- dfun(fef_var)
    for (i in seq_along(val)) {
        refi <- ref[[i]]
        refi_var <- t(apply(attr(refi, "postVar"), 3, diag))
        colnames(refi_var) <- colnames(refi)
        row.names(val[[i]]) <- row.names(val_var[[i]]) <- row.names(refi) ## *
        nmsi <- colnames(refi)
        if (!all(nmsi %in% names(fef))) 
            stop("unable to align random and fixed effects")
        ## 
        for (nm in nmsi) {
            val[[i]][[nm]] <- val[[i]][[nm]] + refi[, nm]
            val_var[[i]][[nm]] <- val_var[[i]][[nm]] + refi_var[, nm]
        }
        val_var[[i]] <- as.data.frame(lapply(val_var[[i]], sqrt),
                                      check.names = FALSE)
    }
    list(values = val, sd = val_var)
}
```

Comment: That was an awesome answer. Thank you !